# Cannot configure dependency object as constructor argument in xml configuration

Tags: xml, configuration, castle-windsor

[This is similar to: [(stackoverflow: multiple constructors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746387/castle-windsor-problem-with-multiple-constructors%20%28multiple%20constructors%29)]

I have the following class:

"ServiceHost:IServiceHost" with the following constructor:

"public ServiceHost(ServiceBase baseService)"

[Note, that this is in fact a derivate of "System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase"].
If I manually - in code -  pass-in my "ServiceToHandle:ServiceBase" as the "baseService" parameter, everything is well. Now, I try to do the same via xm-configuration and I configured two mappings:

```
<component id="TheServiceToControl"
   service="ServiceDemo.ServiceToHandle, ServiceToHandle1"
   type="ServiceDemo.ServiceToHandle, ServiceToHandle1"
>
</component>

<component id="TheServiceController-AKA-ServiceHost"
   service="ServiceDemo.IServiceHost, IServiceHost"
   type="ServiceDemo.ServiceHost, ServiceHost"
>
    <parameters>
        <serviceBase>${TheServiceToControl}</serviceBase>
    </parameters>

</component>
```

When I am loading:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
IServiceHost host = container.Resolve<IServiceHost>();
```

I am expecting a configured host object, which has to be constructed with the additional "TheServiceToControl"
object, (my object) which is derived from "System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase". But I am getting an ugly error:

Unhandled Exception: Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException: Can't create component
'TheServiceController-AKA-ServiceHost' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

'TheServiceController-AKA-ServiceHost' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'System.ServiceProcess.**ServiceBase**' which was not registered.

I tried to add System.ServiceProcess assembly, but I found no way, that it can be made!

If someone probably can explain, what is happeing here, that would be really great!! I've not expected to have to create all objects in the hierarchy.

Thanks anyway and
best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to register your ServiceDemo.ServiceToHandle with the service: ServiceBase
i.e.

```
<component id="TheServiceToControl"
   service="ServiceDemo.ServiceBase, ServiceToHandle1"
   type="ServiceDemo.ServiceToHandle, ServiceToHandle1"
>
</component>
```

When resolving TheServiceController-AKA-ServiceHost it will look for the service ServiceBase, not derived types of it.
This way you should also be able to ommit the parameters section for TheServiceController-AKA-ServiceHost

Kind regards,
Marwijn.

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks; I was - until now ;-)  - too tired last night, to answer
my own question ;-) ....

I have mis-understood, what the xml-tag is. It is the parameter name of
my method in the constructor signature. It is this:

```
public ServiceHost(ServiceBase baseService)
```

This configuration then is successful:

```
        <component id="TheServiceController-AKA-ServiceHost"
               service="ServiceDemo.IServiceHost, IServiceHost"
               type="ServiceDemo.ServiceHost, ServiceHost"
        >
            <parameters>
                <baseService>${TheServiceToControl}</baseService>
            </parameters>

        </component>
```

So, the words "baseService" have to match, not the type.

But many, many thanks !

br,
++mabra